# How to patch or modify action script method dynamically?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I want to modify an Adobe air app without source code. I can decompile the swf file and find the class methods which I am interested in. In theory, I can locate this swf file in memory when this app is running. So can I locate and modify those class methods from adobe air runtime? I have done the same thing successfully for Java.

I google this subject and find nothing. Are there any examples or frameworks to be able to achieve it? Thank you.

Comment: May want to look into this https://github.com/claus/as3swf I used this for modifying and recompile a .swf in code. Should work for Adobe Air.

Comment: Or perhaps you can [generate byte code at runtime](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/emit.html) (though I'm not sure if this would let you override methods of other classes).

Comment: Hi Sunil D., for the emit API, do you know how could I inject it and generate byte code for another running adobe air app? If I'm right, I could use it if I'm in the AVM of that process, right? But how?

Comment: Hi Travis, Thank you for the answer. It seems that as3swf can be used to swf file instead of swf in the process memory. Is that right?

Comment: AS3 has class inheritance *and* prototypical inheritance. If you have access to the class, you should be able to override its methods through its [prototype](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Object.html#prototype).